# Is there a way to print the result of a function on button click in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I'm trying to make a function that tests if the number that is being input by the user can be divided by 3 or 7. This function should work on a click of a button and it looks like this

```
function multiplu(j){
if((j%3==0)||(j%7==0)){
    return true;
}
else{
    return false;
}
}
```

I want the result of that certain function to be displayed in a separate div, in an ul, under the input form, like this:

```
<input type="text" id="newItem">            
<div id="prnt">
    <ul>
    <li>potato</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, i can only make it work by using keyup, like this below

```
$('#newItem').keyup(function(e){
        var code=e.which;
        if (code==13){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('ul').append('<li>'+e.target.value+"</li>");
        }
    });
```

and I do not know where to put the ***multiplu*** function as to make it work.

Do you have any advice? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Asking how to call it? `append('<li>'+e.target.value+":"+ multiplu(Number(e.target.value)) + "</li>");`

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to concatenate the result of `multiplu()` instead of `e.target.value` in to the HTML string you append. You can also use `this.value` as the argument provided to the function.

Finally, note that the `multiplu()` function itself can be simplified to just return the boolean outcome of the modulo operations. Try this:

```js
function multiplu(j) {
  return j % 3 == 0 || j % 7 == 0;
}

$('#newItem').keyup(function(e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('ul').append('<li>' + this.value + ': ' + multiplu(this.value) + "</li>");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="newItem">
<div id="prnt">
  <ul>
    <li>potato</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, that was it! Thank you so much! Do you also know how to make it work with a submit button instead of keyup?

Comment: Sure, use a `click` event handler instead of a `keyup`. If the `submit` button is within a `form`, then hook to the `submit` event of that form.